# Linker Error for Expecta on PNChart iOS

Tags: ios

Referring to : https://github.com/kevinzhow/PNChart/

I downloaded the latest PNChart. Besides of the error "UICountingLabel/UICountingLabel.h not found" which is fixed by setting the build-debug-cert.

I am also getting this error which I can't fix. I tried to set the 'Build Settings -> Search Paths' to YES, but same problem. Anyone knows how to fix this ?

`ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PNChartDemo-giizuxibyqufwkdlwownbowndyew/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Expecta'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PNChartDemo-giizuxibyqufwkdlwownbowndyew/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UICountingLabel'
ld: library not found for -lExpecta
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

.

I also don't understand what is meant by this line :

"Add a pod entry for PNChart to your Podfile pod 'PNChart' "

I tried sending the command "pod 'PNChart'" and error appeared. Ignore this error ? The command 'pod install' works.

Thanks